# How to tell rvm where to install gem packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Normally, when I try to create a gemset using rvm,
it places any gems in $HOME/.rvm

However, on one machine when I run:

```
rvm use 1.8.7-p358@chris_gems --create
```

The command tries to write to the directory /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358

and as a result I get permission errors.

I tried search the web for command line arguments to "rvm" related to the install path
but didn't find anything after a 10 minute search (perhaps I'm sucking at Googling).
Also I tried setting GEM_HOME, GEM_PATH to my home directory.
But that didn't make a difference.

Any suggestions on how I can get rvm to install stuff in $HOME/.rvm
Thanks.

Comment: That one system sounds like it was setup as system-wide rvm. Can you uninstall rvm there and reinstall?

Comment: http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/cli/ - check the options. I think it is `-G|--gems       - root gem path to use`

Comment: @JesseWolgamott Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I cannot uninstall rvm as there are other projects which rely on it actively.  But just knowing that a system wide install may have caused this is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to make it working:

1. add your user to `rvm` group - this will allow your user to write gemsets in system
2. run `rvm user gemsets` - this will make all new gemsets to be created in `$HOME/.rvm`

Comment: How do you return rvm to its previous state before `rvm user gemsets` was run?

Comment: the settings are stored in `~/.rvmrc` and gemsets in `~/.rvm` just remove those and you are back on system